# find vs select_one give me different results in python web scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, css-selectors

hi I am a beginner in Python Beautiful Soup.
I am experimenting to scrape a website from https://www.flipkart.com/laptops/~buyback-guarantee-on-laptops-/pr?sid=6bo%2Cb5g&uniqBStoreParam1=val1&wid=11.productCard.PMU_V2

When I am using find method, I can get the information of price of the products.
However, I cannot get any information about the price when using select_one method.

```
find
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import pandas as pd
    r=requests.get('https://www.flipkart.com/laptops/~buyback-guarantee-on-laptops-/pr?sid=6bo%2Cb5g&uniqBStoreParam1=val1&wid=11.productCard.PMU_V2')
    soup=BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')
    results=soup.find_all('a', attrs={'class':'_31qSD5'})
    for result in results:
        price=result.find('div',{'class':'_1vC4OE _2rQ-NK'}).text[1:]
```

select_one

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
r=requests.get('https://www.flipkart.com/laptops/~buyback-guarantee-on-laptops-/pr?sid=6bo%2Cb5g&uniqBStoreParam1=val1&wid=11.productCard.PMU_V2')
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')
results=soup.select('._31qSD5')
result=results[0]
price=result.select_one('._1vC4OE _2rQ-NK').text[1:]
```

can anyone enlighten me to get price information in select_one method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about trying like the following? This portion `-NK` of the class `_2rQ-NK` seems to be unique, so you can make use of that to get the price.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://www.flipkart.com/laptops/~buyback-guarantee-on-laptops-/pr?sid=6bo%2Cb5g&uniqBStoreParam1=val1&wid=11.productCard.PMU_V2')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')
for items in soup.select('._31qSD5'):
    price = items.select_one('[class$="-NK"]').text[1:]
    print(price)
```